# Ng new doesnt have Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, jasmine-node

Whenever I try to create a new project the karma.conf.js is always missing. Is there a reason why

I expected to have karma.conf.js and all the other stuff but I cant seem to find any of it

Project Files Missing

[image: 1]

Comment: Some questions that might be helpful to solve your problem: Which version of Angular Cli are you using? (run `ng version`) I do get the karma.conf.js with version 14.1.2. Which command did you run? Just `ng new`? Might the file be hidden by your IDE? Did you also check in a terminal? What do you mean with "all the other stuff"?

Comment: Im running 15.0.5. Yea I just did ng new. When I open file explorer I dun see it too.

Comment: karma.config.js is unavailable in angular 15*

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue. But you can create the file in the directory yourself, see [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#configuration).
You just type in the terminal at your project folder:

```
ng generate config karma
```

This worked for me.